# How to set two finger scrolling and keep side scrolling as well (touchpad)

Tags: 12.10, touchpad, scrolling, 13.04

Gnome settings contains an option for enabling two-finger scrolling. This is a nice feature but I require side scrolling as well. Ideally, I would like to have enabled both options. Is that possible? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
```

for horizontal two-finger scrolling rather than edge scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

If your driver is using the synclient for mapping your touchpad you can make a startup script that adds that ability
the command would be:

```
synclient HorizEdgeScroll=1
```

I would test in first and make sure it works as you expect, and if it is satisfactory create a sh script to run.